# Create a temporary table LIKE a regular table

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to create a temporary table that will temporarily shadow a real table and have the same name and structure as the real table.

Independently all features work as expected. This creates a temporary table that hides the previous table until the temporary one is dropped again:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t (test INT);
```

This creates a temporary table with the same structure (but a different name) as the original one:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t2 LIKE t;
```

But this gives an error:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t LIKE t;
```

> 1066 - Not unique table/alias: 't'

The table is a persistent cache that holds grouped data that would take too long when fetched from the original tables. This data is used to generate a report. Sometimes, for partial reports, I want to create the cache freshly from a subset of the data. Temporary tables are ideal for this, because I can overlay the original cache with fresh data, run the report function on it and it is automatically dropped when the connection ends, while all other processes can happily use the real persistent table.

Comment: What do you mean "temporarily shadow a real table"?

Comment: As I said: It "hides the previous table until the temporary one is dropped again".

Comment: Improved answer @AndreKR

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Now that I understand what you're trying to do, this is the closest I can come to doing what you want:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t AS SELECT * FROM t LIMIT 0;
```

This creates a temp table that will 'shadow' the original with *almost* the same schema. Key things that don't carry across are any key definitions, auto_increment properties on those keys, indices and default values.

---

Original answer:
You could rename the tables while you're doing your work. Understand thought that in this version, your shadowed table will be visible to all other connections while the script is running:

```
CREATE TABLE target_temp LIKE target;
```

And then atomically rename the two tables, so the "temporary" table replaces the real one:

```
RENAME TABLE target TO target_old, target_temp TO target;
```

Do your thing...

Then, undo:

```
RENAME TABLE target TO target_temp, target_old TO target;
DROP TABLE target_temp;
```

Comment: I added an explanation to the question.

Comment: Note that I tried in MySQL v8.0 and it does not copies the options (like AUTOINCREMENT, NULL, etc.).

Answer (score -1):

I don't fully understand what you want to do.  But I think you can do a rename and then a create and another rename:

```
rename table t to t_hide;

create table t like t_hide;

. . .

drop table t;

rename table t_hide t;
```

I don't think there is a built-in way to do this.  You could open a transaction. make changes to the `t` and then rollback the transaction to prevent the changes from going through.  That might also be what you want.

EDIT:

An alternative solution would be to turn the original table into a view called `t`.  So, one time you would do:

```
rename table t to t_real;

create view t as select * from t_real;
```

Then you can do something like:

```
create table t_fake like t_real;

alter view t as select * from t_fake;
```

The `alter view` should be "instantaneous" in the sense that it will not affect any other transactions (there will be a clearly defined "before" and "after" for it).

Comment: The table is MyISAM. I tried `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t2 LIKE t; RENAME TABLE t2 TO t;` but it tells me `Table 't' already exists`. Renaming the original table would break all queries accessing `t` until the temporary table is created.

Comment: @AndreKR . . . Renaming the existing table should be a pretty fast operation.  I think you can also lock the table while it is happening (although I haven't locked a table during a rename).

Comment: Doesn't the lock "follow" the rename? Like when I lock t and then `RENAME TABLE t TO t2`, I think t2 is locked and not "any future table that is called t".

Comment: I don't get the point of your edited solution. My question was about a temporary table, which is local to the connection. I think the view would be altered for *all* connected clients - totally different thing.

Comment: @AndrewKR  It said nothing in the original questions that indicated that it was just local to the connection.  Maybe if you explained what you are trying to solve, someone may come up with a better solution.

Comment: I added an explanation to the question.